# USB key does not show up in /dev

Tags: opensuse, udev, usb-drive, dd

We use a USB key system that are contain license files and are provided to unlock proprietary software that we used. The USB drives are small however and get lost easily, so I thought I'd clone them with `dd` for the next time we need to replace one.

Unfortunately, I do not see them in `/dev` as I'd expect. Similarly `lsblk` does not indicate the flash-drive as it would on a regular flash-drive. `dmesg` does indicate that the device is identified, the output is as shown:

```
sam@linux-dax4:~> dmesg | tail
[ 1273.129256] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=04b9, idProduct=0300
[ 1273.129267] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 1273.129272] usb 3-2: Product: USB UltraPro
[ 1273.129275] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: SafeNet Inc.
[ 1313.609126] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 8
[ 1356.107229] usb 3-2: new low-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 1356.398858] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=04b9, idProduct=0300
[ 1356.398868] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 1356.398873] usb 3-2: Product: USB UltraPro
[ 1356.398876] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: SafeNet Inc.
```

I am using VMware to run OpenSuse Leap. I suspect I *might* need to make a custom `udev` rule, but thought I'd ask before I go too much further.

Comment: When you use these things as normal, are they mounted on the filesystem like normal USB sticks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [SafeNet USB UltraPro](http://www.safenet-inc.com/software-monetization/ultrapro/) is not a USB thumb drive.  It's a specialized hardware dongle that provides the correct response when interrogated by software that uses it.  It's specifically designed to be uncloneable; if you could copy them, it would defeat their entire purpose.

Your only solution is to stop losing them.  Some ideas:

1. Tie a string between it and the computer.
2. Use one of those key-finding gadgets you can attach to your keychain.

Comment: Thanks, that was a fear of mine. I just couldn't find any confirmation

Comment: Another ideia is to use/install an internal USB port and place them *inside* the server.